# Drawing colored balls without replacement; tracking maximum balls picked across different colors

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients, balls-in-bins

The following problem is a part of a research problem in a different field that I am working on. I have removed the details from the field on purpose because it is far removed from this piece as such but this is a crucial part of it. So far I have looked into multivariate hypergeometric distribution and the literature on balls and bins problems. I have not encountered this variant or anything that tracks the maximum occupancy in this setting instead of average occupancy across different colors.

Say we are given an urn with ***m<sub>1</sub>*** balls of color ***C<sub>1</sub>***, ***m<sub>2</sub>*** balls of color ***C<sub>2</sub>***, .., ***m<sub>k</sub>*** balls of color ***C<sub>k</sub>*** such that

**m<sub>1</sub> + m<sub>2</sub> + m<sub>3</sub> + .. + m<sub>k</sub> = m.**

Suppose we **draw l <= m balls** from the urn without replacement. Let the number of balls drawn of each color be *l<sub>1</sub>*, *l<sub>2</sub>*,..,*l<sub>k</sub>* such that

***l<sub>1</sub>* + *l<sub>2</sub>* + .. + *l<sub>k</sub>* = *l*.**

What is the probability that **max(*l<sub>1</sub>*,*l<sub>2</sub>*,..*l<sub>k</sub>*) = *t***?

If this case is too general and non-tractable, I would also be happy to know leads for the following special cases:

(a) *m<sub>1</sub>*=*m<sub>2</sub>*=..=*m<sub>k</sub>*,

and/or

(b) k = 4.

Any leads will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the source of the problem?

Comment: This is a small part of a research problem I am working on in a different field. I have rephrased and abstracted out the counting part from the actual scenario.

Comment: It is embarrassing to me personally to write what I am about to write.  In fact, I apologize in advance for writing this, but MathSE does not belong to me.  It is plausible in my mind that other MathSE reviewers will react negatively to your posting because it is missing certain details.  I emphasize that I do not consider such criticism as reasonable, for your posting.  However, I am providing this information as a purely defensive measure, to increase the probability that MathSE reviewers respond as you would like them to respond.  ...see next comment

Comment: Such information as in your comment need to be in the posting itself, with (perhaps) a brief description of the background of the problem.  Further, for the general defensive measures available to you, see [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) 
 for details.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. I am pretty much a newbie here, so this is very helpful. Apologies for not including this detail earlier. I have edited the question now. Thanks a lot again!